# SWTBot becomes very slow

Tags: swtbot

I want to test an Eclipse RPC with SWTBot. The tests itself run fine. But the problem is performance: The first testcases complete in about 1 minute, after a while they take 1 hour or longer. Each testcase seems to take significantly longer than its predecessor although the testcases aren't more complex.

I was suspecting that I have any operations in my tests which cause the bot to wait for timeout a lot but that's not the case. A main culprit seems to be `SWTBotMenu#contextMenu` which takes a lot of the time and I can't figure out why, it's simple operations like `tree().contextMenu("Save").click();`

Answer (score 0):

You can check once `SWTBotPreferences.TIMEOUT`constant. By default it is 5000ms.
I think it should not take one hour time provided that first test case completes in one minute.
How much time application takes if same user actions are done manually instead of SWTBOT. Also try debugging once where exactly it stops in your SWTBOT